# How to echo greetings based on users local time?

Tags: javascript

I want to Echo greetings like Hi (username), (message)! on homepage based on users local time. I know this code is to be used. but don't know how..

```
<script>
var now = new Date();
var hrs = now.getHours(); //getHours takes visitors local time, not server time.

var msg = "";

if (hrs >  0) msg = "Mornin' Sunshine!"; // REALLY early
if (hrs >  6) msg = "Good morning";      // After 6am
if (hrs > 12) msg = "Good afternoon";    // After 12pm
if (hrs > 17) msg = "Good evening";      // After 5pm
if (hrs > 22) msg = "Go to bed!";        // After 10pm


</script>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the existing code? Except for the fact that it's Javascript, not PHP

Comment: Nothings wrong. I just found this javascript and not the php code to echo msg. I don't know how to echo. I am a beginner in php.

Comment: Is your code not working?... I think that is fine

Comment: You have to do it using Javascript... not in server-side.. since you already have the script .. you're good to go.. just use ALERT function in javascript

Comment: @victor Alert will pop the alert box. I want echo it on the page

Comment: Tell me how to get this messages in variable so that I can echo that variable

Comment: @GauravS the message is in a variable. you need [`document.write()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_output.asp) to output to the page in javascript

Comment: may as well sick to js as php does not know the users time.

Comment: Thanks @Memor-X and other folks for suggestion. Solved now!

Answer (score 0):

Use `else if` condition and give `alert`

```html
<script>
var now = new Date();
var hrs = now.getHours(); //getHours takes visitors local time, not server time.
alert(hrs);
var msg = "";

if (hrs >  0) msg = "Mornin' Sunshine!"; // REALLY early
else if (hrs >  6) msg = "Good morning";      // After 6am
else if (hrs > 12) msg = "Good afternoon";    // After 12pm
else if (hrs > 17) msg = "Good evening";      // After 5pm
else msg = "Go to bed!";        // After 10pm

alert(msg);

</script>
```

If you want to display in web page use id and display like following

```
document.getElementById('idname').innerHTML=msg
```

Comment: I don't think it would work, reverse the order of if checks

Comment: He want to display the greetings right? So, based on time we will display it inside the id.

Comment: Consider if hrs is 16 , it will say "Mornin......". As the matter of fact it will always say "Mornin..."

Comment: what @anwerjunaid is correct. the original code gets away with it because each if statement evaluates regardless. the first one is always true but if the second one evaluates to true it overwrites the data in `msg` if it's false `msg` is untouched, and so on and so on. by using `else if` the next if statement will only evaluate if the previous one is false which can never happen unless `hrs <= 0`

Comment: Tell me how to get this messages in variable so that I can echo that variable

Comment: if (hrs >  6) msg = "Mornin' Sunshine!"; // REALLY early
 if (hrs <  12) msg = "Good morning";      // After 6am
 if (hrs < 17) msg = "Good afternoon";    // After 12pm
 if (hrs < 0) msg = "Good evening";      // After 5pm
 if (hrs < 6) msg = "Go to bed!";

Will this condition work?